# Is there easy way to print java variables instead of using system.out.print?

Tags: java, printing

I used to program c++ or c.
in c I used

```
printf();
```

in c++ after using

```
std:cout
```

I can just use

```
cout<< variable;
```

So I want to know is there easy way to print java instead of using system.out.print(without typing system.out everytime)?

ps: I know I can implement a method myself. Just want to know if java has this feature but I missed it.

Comment: No, there is no other "easier" way... BTW `System.out.print` seems easy to me

Comment: By what criteria is `printf`  easy, but `System.out.println` isn't?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik actually I just don't want to type System.out every time

Comment: Sure, in every class create a function `void x(String s) {System.out.println(s);}`. Then just use `x("hello, " + name);`.

Comment: I almost never type it myself: all IDEs come with a template for it. I type `sysout` in Eclipse. You can also `import static System.out`, although I never felt compelled to actually do that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks this is the answer I want.Since I just begin to learn java. Too many types make me tired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most IDEs come with a code template for `System.out.println` so, if it's just about typing, this offers a solution.

However, if you mostly use `System.out.println` to add debug output, you can beat the convenience of any of the built-in idioms you listed with a helper method like this:

```
public static <T> T spy(String msg, T x) { System.out.println(msg+": "+x); return x; }
```

The advantage is that you can insert this into the middle of any expression:

```
String result = dbCall(arg1, spy("Second arg", arg2), arg3);
```

I assume a static import for `spy` above.

Answer (score 3):

No. A few choices:

1. As you say, just implement it in your class.

   ```
   void println(String msg) { // String or Object or whatever
       System.out.println(msg);
   }
   ```
2. Use a variable in your method:

   ```
   PrintStream a = System.out;

   // ...

   a.println("Hi there");
   ```
3. In [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783497/is-there-easy-way-to-print-java-variables-instead-of-using-system-out-print/25783556#comment40324902_25783497), [Marko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik) said you can `import static System.out;` and then just use `out.println` in your code.

Comment: What if the object is not a String or is a primitive?

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag: So the second or soon-to-be third way may be better.

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse... if you type `syso` then press `ctrl + space` it will suggest `System.out.println(...)`.

Comment: +1. Actually, this is true for most IDEs, and is even faster than implementing your own static method!

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans, type **sout** and press tab.

It will automatically convert to System.out.println

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to implement by your self with a shorter method name like this

```
public static void println(String msg){
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Or, choose something like `log4j`,which does many things for your in different log levels to do this with a more concise method name.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , yeah, you are right, and I just give an example since the OP comes from C. I updated my answer and thank you!